# Context menu new class on right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I Am using the following scripts for a context-menu. This all works perfect for me, but I miss some option I want/need to use but I  don't know how.

https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

When I do a right mouse click on the class '.task' I want there to be an additional class for more style. but that class has to only be enabled when I right click on something.

Example:
(Look at the folder 'nieuws')
How it looks now:

[image: no]

How I want it to look:

[image]

Code:
Html which triggers contaxt-menu by the .task class

```
<div class="pointer task" data-id="0">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="pointer task" data-id="1">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Etc.

Code 'Context Menu':
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MYLoWY

Comment: You need to add YOUR code to the question in a [mcve]

Comment: Your PEN does not attach itself to the list items. I expect you want the _Go To Grocery_ to be blue if the user right-clicked on that item, right?

Comment: Hi mplungjan, de codepen has already been added and works perfect. it triggers on the '.task' . i want '.task' to be blue if the user clicked that with right click.. but i want it also transparent when the user clicks away from it.. the effect need to be; that it's only colored when the context menu is show

Comment: The codepen triggers anywhere on the page